# R studio: Dynamic Time Wrapping for time series with more than 1 variable of interest

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, purrr, dtw

This question is related to this post:
[How to apply dtw algorithm on multiple time series in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945769/how-to-apply-dtw-algorithm-on-multiple-time-series-in-r)

The original post has a dataframe that consists of only 1 variable in interest: `speed.kph.ED`.

```
#data: 8 observations, 3 cars 
file.ID2 <- c("Cars_03", "Cars_03", "Cars_03", 
              "Cars_03", "Cars_03", "Cars_03", "Cars_03", "Cars_03", "Cars_04", 
              "Cars_04", "Cars_04", "Cars_04", "Cars_04", "Cars_04", "Cars_04", 
              "Cars_04", "Cars_05", "Cars_05", "Cars_05", "Cars_05", "Cars_05", 
              "Cars_05", "Cars_05", "Cars_05")
speed.kph.ED <- c(129.3802848, 
                  129.4022304, 129.424176, 129.4461216, 129.4680672, 129.47904, 
                  129.5009856, 129.5229312, 127.8770112, 127.8221472, 127.7672832, 
                  127.7124192, 127.6575552, 127.6026912, 127.5478272, 127.4929632, 
                  134.1095616, 134.1205344, 134.1315072, 134.1534528, 134.1644256, 
                  134.1753984, 134.1863712, 134.197344)

df <- data.frame(file.ID2, speed.kph.ED)
df
```

Per suggested by the accepted answer, here is the procedure to calculate the distance between 3 cars (3 time series) using dtw:

```
library(dtw)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# Split your data frame into a list by file.ID2
ds <- split(df, df$file.ID2)
ds

# Use expand.grid to make all combinations of your names, file.ID2 and your values
Names <- expand.grid(unique(df$file.ID2), unique(df$file.ID2))
Values <- expand.grid(ds, ds)

# purrr:map_dbl iterates through all row-combinations of Values and returns a vector of doubles
Dist <- map_dbl(1:nrow(Values), ~dtw(x = Values[.x,]$Var1[[1]]$speed.kph.ED, y = Values[.x,]$Var2[[1]]$speed.kph.ED)$distance)

# Bind answer to Names
library(dplyr)
ans <- Names %>% 
  mutate(distance = Dist)

ans
```

I am wondering what if I have another two variables that I also want to take into consideration when calculating the distance between 3 cars (3 time series)?

For example, let's say I have another 2 variables `score.kph.ED` and `rating.kph.ED`:

```
score.kph.ED <- c(1:24)
rating.kph.ED <- c(25:48)


df <- data.frame(file.ID2, speed.kph.ED, score.kph.ED, rating.kph.ED)
df
```

Now, the distance between the 3 cars are calculated not only based on `speed.kph.ED`, but also based on `score.kph.ED` and `rating.kph.ED`.

How can I modify the existing code so that I can achieve this goal?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: How will you do this for one example without `map_dbl` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Do you have an example of calculating distance between 3 cars  (3 time series) ?

Comment: @RonakShah The original example is already calculating the distance between 3 cars (but only using  `speed.kph.ED` to calculate that distance).  I want to do the same thing, but to use `speed.kph.ED`, `score.kph.ED`, and `rating.kph.ED` to calculate the distance among 3 cars.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(file.ID2, speed.kph.ED, score.kph.ED, rating.kph.ED)
ds <- split(df, df$file.ID2)
Names <- expand.grid(unique(df$file.ID2), unique(df$file.ID2))
Values <- expand.grid(ds, ds)

cols <- names(df)[-1]
result <- map_dfc(cols, function(col) map_dbl(1:nrow(Values),
  ~dtw(x = Values[.x,]$Var1[[1]][[col]], 
       y = Values[.x,]$Var2[[1]][[col]])$distance))

names(result) <- paste0('dist.', cols)
cbind(Names, result)


#     Var1    Var2 dist.speed.kph.ED dist.score.kph.ED dist.rating.kph.ED
#1 Cars_03 Cars_03           0.00000                 0                  0
#2 Cars_04 Cars_03          25.66538                71                 71
#3 Cars_05 Cars_03          69.72117               191                191
#4 Cars_03 Cars_04          25.66538                71                 71
#5 Cars_04 Cars_04           0.00000                 0                  0
#6 Cars_05 Cars_04          96.00103                71                 71
#7 Cars_03 Cars_05          69.72117               191                191
#8 Cars_04 Cars_05          96.00103                71                 71
#9 Cars_05 Cars_05           0.00000                 0                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called multivariate DTW,
and you can simplify things by using the `proxy` package.
Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776685/5793905),
but you can essentially do what you want like this (using the variables from your example):

```
proxy::dist(lapply(ds, function(x) { x[, -1L] }), method = "dtw")
```